# Flag and Delete GMail Messages with Delphi/Indy

Tags: delphi, imap, indy, flags

How can I delete and flag messages in GMail with Delphi 10.3.3/stock Indy.

The following approach does not work (I ommitted the try/finally stuff to compress the code):

```
var
  imap: TIdIMAP4;
  msg: TIdMessage;
  ...
  imap := TIdIMAP4.Create(nil);
  ...
  if imap.SelectMailBox('INBOX') then
  begin
    for i := 1 to imap.MailBox.TotalMsgs do
    begin
      imap.Retrieve(i, msg);
      imap.getUID(i, UID);
      ...
      imap.UIDStoreFlags(UID, sdReplace, msg.Flags - [mfSeen]);  -> DOESNT WORK
      ...
      imap.UIDStoreFlags(UID, sdReplace, msg.Flags + [mfAnswered]);  -> DOESNT WORK
      ...
      imap.UIDDeleteMsg(UID); -> DOESNT WORK
      ...
    end;
  end;
  ...
  imap.disconnect;
  imap.free;
  ...
```

Is there any update statement that I omitted? Or do I need to set special settings within the gmail account?

UPDATE: Deletion now works but the flags are still not set. Deletion showed with a slight delay but the flags persist...

Answer (score 1):

Found the solutuion: My Impatience caused it.

It takes up to some minutes until the flag change is reflected in GMail. As I am constructing a forwarder running every 30s I will store the UIDs of seen messages of the last hour or so and take this list into account too.

Comment: I see stores reflected at once. Is it possible that you're doing some inappropriate caching?

Comment: The Gmail web UI can take some time to reflect changes done by IMAP.

Comment: Yes, the Web interface reflects with delay but also in the delphi deamon I set seen and do not see it on next connect. I use raw Indy components and disconnect after verey "round". However, with my UID list it works fine as I delete the messages after forwarding.

Comment: @MichaSchumann if you are scanning for new emails every 30s, then you are not using IMAP effectively. You should not be disconnecting after each scan. Just leave the connection open and use IMAP's [`IDLE` command](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2177) instead to receive new emails in real time, no polling needed. However, [Indy does not support IDLE at this time](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/147), but it should not be difficult to implement manually. Also, don't call `UIDStoreFlags()` twice, once to subtract and then to add. Modify the flags as needed and then use a single call.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I already recogniced that connecting takes a lot of time. I will try to implement IDLE. Regarding the flags - I only showed what I do in different parts in my code example, of course I use only one call.

Comment: For some reason the messages I delete in my forwarder are no longer deleted in gmai and still reside in the original folder. In gmail I have the standard setting for SMTP to delete immediately.